# Function to ensure window height

Tags: window

Is there a function to ensure (or at least try) that a given window has a height of N lines, by shrinking it (or enlarging it) as needed?

- If N is too much (or not enough) for a given scenario, then a reaching best-effort value of M lines is ok.
- It's safe to assume that there are multiple, stacked windows (one is above the other, instead of side to side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 1 window in a frame the only way is shrink frame itself.

If you have many windows it could be impossible to ensure height of the particular window due to minimal height restriction.

So what is the usecase? Whenever you split vertically to have one of the window N lines if possible? Then use `(split-window-vertically 10)`, it will create 2 windows, the top one with 10 rows, the bottom one with the rest.

Comment: Questioning the original question rarely tends to be a useful answer, and would have been better expressed as a comment.

I've edited my question.

Comment: @vemv, Really sorry to make you unhappy with my answer not expressed as a comment. Peace.

Comment: ✌️ Basically it's how SE works. Anyway pointing out to the optional `split-window-vertically` was spot on - by passing it a negative argument I can solve my original problem. Thanks!

Comment: FYI it's not about me getting offended, it's about giving me the possibility to reply in a reasonable format. Hard to reply point-by-point to an pseudo-answer in a comment. Hope it's useful!

Comment: NP, I actually had the same in mind -- reasonable formatting. A couple of times I did comments that were messy.

Comment: @MaximKim and OP: It's constructive that you both edited the Q & A, based on your dialog in comments. Comments can be deleted at any time - improving the Q and A is the right approach - they are what remain and are searchable. If you think you've already incorporated what is needed from your comments you can delete them. (No requirement to do so, though.) Thx.